# Invalid links after migrating from Confluence 3.5 to Confluence 4.2.3

Tags: confluence

We are editing lots of pages with text in Confluence version 3.5 but in one good day, we decide to upgrade our system to version 4.3.2. As a result, now, we have big problems with data.

All links in projects start being invalid and markup of text-fields changed, I think it connected with major changes in Confluence.

So now I trying to find way how to update this data and return nice view.
Is there any plugins? Or scripts? Or any default features of Confluence to doing this work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**New Editor**

The `Wiki Markup editor` has been removed in Confluence 4 and replaced with a new `XHTML-based editor`.

Confluence 4 introduced a [Brand New Editor](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+4.0+Release+Notes#Confluence40ReleaseNotes-BrandNewEditor) with `macro placeholders` and a `macrobrowser`.

By default you won't see wiki markup anymore in the edit mode, but placeholders. There is one wiki macro called `Wiki-Markup` which u can use to enter wiki markup.

And for users who are very familiar with wiki markup there us an Autoformatting feature, which lets you type wiki markup into the editor and it will "auto-format" the text on the fly.

Have you read [Planning for Confluence 4](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Planning+for+Confluence+4)?

Also, please take a look at [Migration from Wiki Markup to XHTML-Based Storage Format](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Migration+from+Wiki+Markup+to+XHTML-Based+Storage+Format)

Regarding your macros you may try

- [Re-running Migration](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Migration+from+Wiki+Markup+to+XHTML-Based+Storage+Format#MigrationfromWikiMarkuptoXHTML-BasedStorageFormat-Re-runningMigration) or
- [Re-attempt Migration](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Migration+from+Wiki+Markup+to+XHTML-Based+Storage+Format#MigrationfromWikiMarkuptoXHTML-BasedStorageFormat-Re-attemptMigration)

> The most common reason for content to be in this state is that a non
>   4.0 compatible macro (or unknown macro) was found on the page.
>
> There are two possible fixes for this situation -
>
> 1. Install a 4.0 compatible version of the macro. See Plugin Development Upgrade FAQ for 4.0.
> 2. Edit the page to no longer use the problematic macro.

So as stated i would suggest you look for compatible versions of the macros/plugins and force a re-migratition:

- URL: /admin/force-upgrade.action
- URL: /admin/unmigratedwikicontent.action

What do you mean by `the links are invalid`?

Comment: i have link eg "ftp://ftp/blah/blah.doc" and after update it's not works, before i use [link|text], what i do next i found confluence article about links and migrate all links with changing format to XHTML and it works now but i still have some problems with text fields. And btw, i don't know why but your solution not solve my problem((

Comment: can you show us (1) how the link target looks like after migration (2) wiki markup code or how the link looks in the editor (screenshot)

Comment: In addition (a) have you checked to log files of the migration process for errors? (b) what does Confluence says when you [re-attempt migration](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Migration+from+Wiki+Markup+to+XHTML-Based+Storage+Format#MigrationfromWikiMarkuptoXHTML-BasedStorageFormat-Re-attemptMigration)? Pages found? Update required?

Comment: What about problems with links i think i solve this problem, in base links looks like <ac:link><ri:page ri:space-key="SpaceKey" ri:content-title='ftp://ftp/blah/blah.doc'/></ac:link> or <a href='http://stackoverflow.com'>Advice</a>

Comment: Thats good! What about the rest of the wiki pages and macros?

Comment: i send report to customware, about this problem, and now wait an answer, this problem is not resolved yet(